# Getting CakePHP to read cookies set by WordPress for user authentication

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, cookies

I'm trying to allow a person who is logged into a WordPress application to also be logged into my CakePHP application.

WordPress writes a cookie named `wordpress/` (IE) and `wordpress_logged_in` (Google Chrome). I am very confused about these two different names the cookies get set in the browser when I looked into the temporary files. I am not sure why.

I'm working on reading these cookies but not sure how CakePHP does it.

Currently cookies are set for **localhost/** and my CakePHP installation is in **wordpress/myapp**. I used a simple CakePHP file to read the cookies and was successful.

I just need a sample of CakePHP authentication after reading a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this before, but I think it is actually possible.

Wordpress saves two cookies on login - the username, and the double-hashed password. You can use WP's is_user_logged_in() function without having to read the cookies. To do this outside WordPress:

```
<?php
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Then you can:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "You are logged in.";
}
else {
    echo "Please login.";
};
?>
```

I hope that helps.